# How do I create syntax nodes in Roslyn from scratch?

Tags: c#, vb.net, roslyn

I would like to generate syntax nodes with the Roslyn API without having a pre-existing syntax node. That is, I cannot simply use the WithXYZ() methods on an existing object to modify it because there is no existing object.

For example, I would like to generate an InvocationExpressionSyntax object. Assuming a constructor was available, I could do something like

```
var invoke = new InvocationExpressionSyntax(expression, arguments);
```

But the constructor for `InvocationExpressionSyntax` seems to not be public.

http://www.philjhale.com/2012/10/getting-started-with-roslyn.html

this blog suggests that I can use an API such as

```
Syntax.InvocationExpression()
```

but I don't see what `Syntax` refers to, and I don't see anything that resembles it in the Roslyn API.

I did find Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.SyntaxFactory that lets me do

```
var invoke = SyntaxFactory.InvocationExpression().WithExpression(expression);
```

And this works well enough for me. There is also `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SyntaxFactory` for anyone wondering.

Is `SyntaxFactory` the proper way to create new syntax nodes?

The way I found SyntaxFactory.InvocationExpression was by looking at the PublicAPI.txt file in the roslyn source code (https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) under the src/Compilers/VisualBasic/Portable directory. Otherwise, I don't see where `SyntaxFactory` is documented.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the `SyntaxFactory` type is the way to create syntax nodes from scratch.

Answer (score 20):

As the other answer stated, the `SyntaxFactory` is the correct class to use.  As you have found there are two syntax factories available, `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SyntaxFactory` and `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.SyntaxFactory`, depending on which language you are using.

Usually the calls into the `SyntaxFactory` are chained together, so you end up with many calls to the `SytnaxFactory` methods to generate even simple lines of code.  For example, the code `Console.WriteLine("A");` would be represented by the following calls to the Syntax Factory:

```
var console = SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("Console");
var writeline = SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("WriteLine");
var memberaccess = SyntaxFactory.MemberAccessExpression(SyntaxKind.SimpleMemberAccessExpression, console, writeline);

var argument = SyntaxFactory.Argument(SyntaxFactory.LiteralExpression(SyntaxKind.StringLiteralExpression, SyntaxFactory.Literal("A")));
var argumentList = SyntaxFactory.SeparatedList(new[] { argument });

var writeLineCall =
    SyntaxFactory.ExpressionStatement(
    SyntaxFactory.InvocationExpression(memberaccess,
    SyntaxFactory.ArgumentList(argumentList)));
```

If you are unsure of how to generate nodes for some specific code, Kirill Osenkov created the [Roslyn Quoter project](http://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/) on GitHub, which you can use to generate the `SyntaxFactory` code for you.

I recently did a [blog post](https://johnkoerner.com/csharp/creating-code-using-the-syntax-factory/) on this topic if you would like to read further.

Comment: Do you know of any examples using the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.SyntaxFactory?